# open.mapquestapi.com: http-response decoding in Java

Tags: java, http, decode

I want to use open.mapquestapi.com within Java. It works fine, as far as I have to care for (german) umlauts, let's take as example the german city "Köln".

In Java, i don't get the mapquestapi-response decode correctly, i always end up with "KÃ¶ln".

```
// String query.. e.g. "Hohenstaufenring 25, Köln"
URI uri = new URI("http", "open.mapquestapi.com", "/nominatim/v1/search", "format=json&addressdetails=1&email=[...]&countrycodes=DE&q=" + query, null);
URL mapqOsm = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mapqOsm.openStream(), "UTF-8"));

String response = "";
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  response += line;
}
reader.close();
```

I have to decode "response" another way, but I don't have any ideas left how to decode it correctly. Sourcefile encoding is UTF-8.

How do I decode open.mapquestapi.com-response in Java correctly?